# lm_lid doesn't run when lid closed

Tags: laptop, xrandr, acpi, lid, displaylink

I have an xps 15 7590 laptop with ubuntu 20.4 
and I'm using a displaylink driver that has a problem that when the laptop lid is closed the computer become so laggy it's unusable: https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/181
I'm trying to run a command every time the lid is closed to fix the problem, running the command alone on terminal works but when it's in the lid.sh file it doesn't
I did the following steps:

I've created a /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid file with the following content:

```
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

and created a lid.sh file in /etc/acpi with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=eDP-1
MODE=1920x1080
MYUSER=eyal

grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
# lid has been just closed

if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then
    # run by root (triggered by lid closing)

    DISPLAY=:0.0 su $MYUSER -c "xrandr --output ${NAME} --mode ${MODE} --pos 0x0 --rotate normal"

else
     # run by user manually
     xrandr --output ${NAME} --mode ${MODE} --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
fi

fi
```

I made the lid.sh executable to all
but it still doesn't work

thank you for the help

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to solve this? I am running into the same issue. `acpi_listen` shows that the event name is correct (same as in your post) but the `lid.sh` does not seem to execute